# slf4j logging to specific package

Tags: log4j, slf4j

The output of the logs should come from specific package.

Now in log4j.properties, have added the following property:
**log4j.logger.com.pack1=DEBUG, stdout**

PFB the code (test.java class in com.pack1.logging package):

```
package com.pack1.logging;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class test {

private static Logger myLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("xyz");

static {
    myLogger.debug("test-my");
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(test.class).debug("with class");

}

}
```

After using the above code,

**Expected o/p:**
test-my
with class

**Actual o/p:**
with class

I somehow want the output from that specific package "com.pack1".
Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have configured it differently in your log4j.properties, the logger that you are getting from

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("xyz")
```

is probably the root logger, which is probably set to log at `INFO` level, which is why you do not see "test-my" in the log output.

On the other hand, since your `test` class is in the `com.pack1` package, the logger that you get from

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger(test.class)
```

is the one that you have configured with the line

```
log4j.logger.com.pack1=DEBUG, stdout
```

in your log4j.properties file, so that is why your debug "with class" message appears.